# sql query getting name and desc from one main table and two sub tables.

Tags: sql, join

Hi i have a table structure like this.

table

```
**geoinfo**
id
name
desc
```

I have table

```
**zip_to_city**
id, 
zip_id fk geoinfo
city_id fk geoinfo
```

than i also have

```
**zip_to_state** 
id
zip_id fk geoinfo
state_id fk geoinfo
```

I want to query so that I am able to get each zip with the respective city and state. I don't want the id, i want the name. geoinfo is the main table containing name and description of each geoinfo.

Whats the best query to do this?

Comment: how is the table related to each other?

Comment: there isn't enough information on how the tables relate. What is a geoinfo for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT city_geo.geography_name as city,state_geo.geography_name as state, zip_geo.geography_name as postalCode
FROM zip_to_city zc, zip_to_state zs, 
geoinfo city_geo, geoinfo state_geo, geoinfo zip_geo
where zc.city_id = city_geo.id
AND state_geo.id= zs.state_id
AND zip_geo.id = zc.zip_id 
AND zip_geo.id = zs.zip_id
AND zip_geo.name = ?
```

This works for me and gets what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this if I correctly understood your tables:

```
SELECT zip_to_city.city_id,zip_to_state.state_id FROM geoinfo 
INNER JOIN zip_to_city ON geoinfo.id=zip_to_city.id 
INNER JOIN zip_to_state ON geoinfo.id=zip_to_state=id where geoinfo.id='some value'
```

Comment: the OP asked for `name`, not the `ID`

Comment: By my reading of the question, the field-list is supposed to be something like `zip_geoinfo.name, city_geoinfo.name, state_geoinfo.name` (where `zip_geoinfo` etc. are aliases for three separate `JOIN`ings of `geoinfo`).

Comment: yeah that's true but he doesn't have name in the tables but only the id, so maybe the name is stored in geoinfo? so : zip_to_city.geoinfo